# Implication about homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, analysis, continuity, continuous-homomorphisms

> Let $f:(X,\tau_1) \to (Y,\tau_2) $ be a bijection and $A \subseteq X.$ Then TFAE

a)f is a homeomorphism

b) $f(\overline A) = \overline {f(A)}$

c) $f(int(A)) = int(f(A))$

Which means we should show a $\Rightarrow$ b $\Rightarrow$ c $\Rightarrow$ a

How can I show $$f(\overline A) = \overline {f(A)} \Rightarrow f(int(A)) = int(f(A))$$

($\overline A $ is closure of $A$ and $int(A)$ is interior of $A$)

We can say $f$ is closed and continuous from assumption. Namely, $f$ is open and continuous. Thus $f(int(A)) \subseteq int(f(A))$. I have problem about showing $int(f(A)) \subseteq f(int(A))$

Comment: Bijection is not the same as homeomorphism. Is $f$ supposed to be a homeomorphism?

Comment: Are you sure we don't miss a quantifier here? $$\big( \forall A\subseteq X: f(\bar A)=\overline{f(A)}\big)\ \implies\ \big( \forall A\subseteq X: f(\mathrm{int}\, A)=\mathrm{int}\,f(A)\big)$$
Also, how do we know $f$ is closed?

Comment: @Berci First thanks for answer. We have $f(\bar A) \subseteq \overline {(f(A))}$ and $\overline {(f(A))} \subseteq f(\bar A)$ from equality. $f(\bar A) \subseteq \overline {(f(A))}$ iff f is continuous and $\overline {(f(A))} \subseteq f(\bar A)$ iff f is closed. They are theorems I can write their proofs if it is necessary.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. I have rewritten it you can see easier. Bijection and b) bring being homeomorphism

Answer (score 1):

Prove that a) and b) are equivalent and then prove that a) and c) are equivalent. a) implies b) is clear. Suppose b) holds. If A is a closed set than b) shows that f(A) is closed too. If U is open then its complement A is closed, so f(A) is closed. But f(A) is the complement of f(U) (because f is a bijection). Hence f(U) is open. The fact that f maps open sets to open sets and closed sets to closed sets shows that a) holds. A similar argument shows that c) is equivalent to a).

Comment: Thank you. Can not we say b implies c?

Comment: Of course b) implies c). But you don't have to prove equivalences in any particular order. Since b) implies a) and a) implies c) it follows by pure logic that b) implies c).

Comment: Since iff is an equivalence relation, isn’t it? I wonder b implies c. If it will be in final exam I think I can not show anything about it. If it isn’t too much trouble for you could you please write down something about b implies c? Very very thanks :)

Comment: Even in an exam you are not expected prove the equivalence in that particular order. In any case if you write down the proof of b) implies a) and follow it up with the proof of a) implies you will get a proof of b) implies c), right?

Comment: I desired to ask if the question in exam will be only “b implies c” part of theorem? I have no problem about changing orders.

Comment: I understand your concern now. You can use a) as an intermediate step in proving b) implies c). I cannot think of any simpler proof of b) implies c).

Comment: I’ve done it with using a but it is really hard to me without a. Thanks a lot for your concern